# Checking if network drive is connected in python?

Tags: python

I want to verify inside a python script running on Windows (7) that a network drive is connected and available.
I would do something like the following:

```
import os
connection_works = os.path.exists("F:\\")
```

However this seems to simply hang while the connection is down, returning True when the connection is reestablished. Using glob (my next idea) exhibits the same behavior. What would be the smart way of doing this?

Answer (score -2):

You're just saving the output from the os.path.exists() into connection_works. Try something like:

```
if os.path.exists("F:\\"):
    print('path exists'):
else:
    print('path does not exists):
```

Comment: _However this seems to simply hang while the connection is down, returning True when the connection is reestablished._ Makes me think that they are printing the value. `== True` is bad for at least two reasons, by the way, just use `if os.path.exists("F:\\"):`.

Comment: Yes, the point is I want to know if, at a given time, the drive was available. I can't do that easily if the method always returns True, but takes varying amounts of time to do so. I'd like something that returns False if the drive is not immediately available.

Comment: If that is what you want, you should update your question to reflect this.